# emacs -rails-reloaded does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs

I wanted to use emacs-rails-reloaded. So, I installed it from [github](https://github.com/dima-exe/emacs-rails-reloaded). However, when I do the bytecompile step, I get a warning about cl package being required at runtime. So, I added the following to my .emacs file.

```
(require 'cl)
```

However, the warning still persists. My complete .emacs file is as follows:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins")
(setq load-path (cons (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/emacs-rails-reloaded") load-path))
(require 'snippet)
(require 'find-recursive)
(require 'cl)
(require 'inf-ruby)
(autoload 'inf-ruby "inf-ruby" "Run an inferior Ruby process" t)
(autoload 'inf-ruby-setup-keybindings "inf-ruby" "" t)
(eval-after-load 'ruby-mode
  '(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'inf-ruby-setup-keybindings))
(require 'rails-autoload)
(require 'color-theme)
(setq visible-bell t)
```

When I run M-x rails/console, I get a message saying 'Symbol's function definition is void: inferior-ruby-mode'. I had installed inf-ruby from [github](https://github.com/nonsequitur/inf-ruby/blob/master/inf-ruby.el) to solve that but it does not seem to be working. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> latest commit 0b95b63805
>   dima-exe authored **4 years ago**

This could have been your hint. Yes, it's outdated and unsupported.

The only somewhat updated version of `emacs-rails` I know of is [remvee's fork of the original mode](https://github.com/remvee/emacs-rails).

Comment: Yeah, I have now realized that emacs-rails is outdated and unsupported. Thanks for pointing me to remvee's fork. I'll try that out sometime.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Emacs are you using? If it's 24 you can get inf-ruby from marmalade - http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/inf-ruby

You need to install marmalade as a package repository, detailed help for which is available here: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA#toc2

Comment: I am using Emacs 24. I already have inf-ruby installed. I have inf-ruby.el in ~/.emacs.d/plugins and in the first line of my .emacs I add that folder to my load-path. So, I thought that inf-ruby was loaded properly. M-x ruby-mode works fine too actually.

Comment: well, you' need to paste some of your config then.

Comment: You have my .emacs pasted above. Please let me know what other configuration files you need.

Comment: There's no such function as `inferior-ruby-mode` in the `inf-ruby` package.